# javafx sortedlist error while clearing

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, sortedlist

Using JavaFX 8 new feature SortedList, binded to a TableView sorting comparator.
my implementation looks like :

```
SortedList<T> sorted = myObservableList.sorted();
myTable.setItems(sorted);
sorted.comparatorProperty().bind(myTable.comparatorProperty());
```

`myObservableList` is an empty `ObservableList` at startup.
I set `myTable` comparator property through FXML.

My use case is :

1. populate `myObservableList` with data (sorting and display are working bot fine)
2. clear `myObservableList` -> throw `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` with a negative index
3. re-populate `myObservableList` with some other data

I don't know why clearing the backed list `myObservableList` throws an error. Why the sortedlist is looking for indices while clearing ?
I tried first to clear the sorted list, but this operation not supported.

Comment: In JavaFX 8.0, when I try to addAll to a SortedList, I get errors too that go all the way back to AbstractList. My solution is to keep a reference to the ObservableList that is at the base of the SortedList and to add to that list instead, which does properly propagate to the SortedList. Sounds like an FX bug indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to the latest build `Build b114` and that fixes the bug, as it really sounds like an FX bug

But, be careful, now the addAll() breaks, need to create a for loop and call add().